# How do I properly extend an angularJS factory

Tags: javascript, angularjs

If I have some base factory that has a bunch of methods I want to extend to a bunch of other factories such as

```
function TestFactory() {

    var service = {};

    service.name = null
    service.lastname = null

    service.screech = function() {
       alert(service.name + service.lastname)
    }

    return service;

}
```

And I want to extend that functionality to another service such as

```
function NewFactory() {

    var service = angular.copy(TestFactory)

    service.name = 'Cool'
    service.lastname = 'Guy'

    return service;

}
```

I would expect NewFactory.screech() to alert "CoolGuy", but it appears it is calling the screech method in the scope of the original TestFactory where name and lastname are null.

How can I accomplish this pattern?

I have also tried using angular.extend but had the same result.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Change `service` to `this` inside the definition of `service.screech`:

```
service.screech = function() {
   alert(this.name + this.lastname)
}
```

It didn't work because when you referred to `service` *inside* the function, due to [closure](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Closures), `service` was hard-coded to the `service` object at the time of definition. The reference was not updated when you made the copy. `this`, on the other hand, is dynamic and always refers the the object that the function is being called on, e.g. with `service.screech()`.

Also, you need to set `service` to a copy of the object *resulting* from the `TestFactory`, not to a copy of the `TestFactory` itself:

```
var service = angular.copy(TestFactory())
```

Comment: Thanks a lot for the quick response! A note for any future readers, if you are using angular's dependency injection to get your instance of TestFactory it will already be delivered as an object and it will be impossible / unnecessary to call it as a function.

Answer (score 2):

Change service variable to this. Closure will bind the service variable to the function instead service should be using scope of the object so that it can be inherited.

All functions inside the factory should be using this to refer the object.

```
function TestFactory() {

    var service = {};

    service.name = null
    service.lastname = null

    service.screech = function() {
       alert(this.name + this.lastname)
    }

    return service;

}
```

Also change the following code to return the factory object not the Factory Function

```
function NewFactory() {

    var service = angular.copy(TestFactory())

    service.name = 'Cool'
    service.lastname = 'Guy'

    return service;

}
```

Comment: Thanks for the quick response, if I could mark two answers as correct I would!

Comment: that's fine. :)